Horror movie about people in a building on an island
Ok so, I can't remember any detailed moments, but I can recall quite a few random moments, as far as I can recall the film is about a group of people getting stuck on some sort of island with a building, then they start dying one by one. (naturally)
One woman was addicted to smoking, and she finds a vending machine with some packs in it, she buys it, and when she smokes it I guess she gets poisoned by it or something, and I believe she dies and falls into the ocean (she was outside on some kinda balcony)
The person who took them to the island had separated from them, and he was the only one who could drive the boat, I distinctly recall they found him, dead and hung up by like, hundreds of hooks.
one guy had to like, climb across these water pipes on the ceiling to get past a trap, but the pipe was also a trap and he died somehow or another
then finally they find out one of them was the killer because he told the last guy to climb across the pipe, and i guess he convinced the driver to go there.
I think it might have been in a hospital, the film was either American or British, and it seemed late 90s early to mid 2000s

Ah, Mindhunters... The most searched obscure film in the known universe.

ah, thank you, i tried to find another question for it. but couldn't find it.
